# PsExec to open a program that interacts via the Desktop and reports messages to CMD

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, psexec

I want to run a script on a remote machine. The script needs to be aware of the desktop, so cannot be run as a background process. To do this, I've been using the following command:

```
psexec \\RemoteMachine -u username -p password -i #ID cmd /c python C:\script.py
```

This runs the script correctly, but the STDOUT of the script is only displayed of the RemoteMachine. The only message sent back to psexec is:

> python.exe exited on RemoteMachine with error code 0.

NOTE: I can get the desired STDOUT behaviour if I run

```
psexec \\RemoteMachine -u username -p password cmd
```

and then navigate to the script via cmd. But this runs the script as a background process with no access to a user session or desktop.

So, how can I run the script such that it's desktop aware and such that the STDOUT appears in the original psexec cmd window?